# Restricting data in PouchDB

Tags: database, security, couchdb, pouchdb

I have an offline ready application that I am currently building in electron.

The core requirements are that all data is restricted (have to be a user to read or write) and that within that data some data is further restricted to a user, (account information, messages, etc...)

Now I do **not** want to replicate any data offline that a user should **not** have access to (this is because all the data can be seen using the devtools regardless of restriction) so essentially I only want to sync data to PouchDB's offline store if that user has access to it as well as all the data all users have access to.

Now I have read the following posts/guides but I am still a little confused.

- https://pouchdb.com/2015/04/05/filtered-replication.html
- https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-multiple-user-app-with-pouchdb-couchdb/
- [Restricting Access to local PouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187837/restricting-access-to-local-pouchdb)

From my understanding filtering is a bad choice performance wise even though it could do what I want.

Setting up a proxy would work but it then essentially becomes a REST api and the data synchronization falls apart.

And the final option which I think is what I want is to have a database for every user that would contain their private information and then additional databases to hold the information that is available to every user.

The only real question I have with this approach is how is data handled that is private but shared between two users (messages, etc...)

I am more after an overarching view of how the data should be stored as opposed to code examples, just really struggling with the conceptual architecture of the application.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to your problem. One solution looks very promising: IBM Cloudant has started work on [Cloudant Envoy](https://github.com/cloudant-labs/envoy), a proxy simulating the CouchDB interface instead of a simple REST API. You can read more about it on the site for [Envoy over at ibm.com](https://developer.ibm.com/open/openprojects/cloudant-envoy/). A [custom replicator for PouchDB](https://github.com/glynnbird/pouchdb-envoy) is also available on Github.

There's also a [blog post on Medium.com](https://medium.com/offline-camp/scaling-offline-first-with-envoy-ada42d130cfc#.1yp06f70z) on this.

The idea is the same as the much older [Couchbase Sync Gateway](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/sync-gateway/index.html). Although Couchbase has common roots with CouchDB, I have not tracked if they still support replication with CouchDB.

The easiest way to start would be to create a single database per user on the server, and a common database that you just pull the shared data from. Let me know if you need more info on this solution.

Comment: That sounds like a really good solution thanks for the all the information, in this scenario what would I use to handle data private to two users (i.e messages) would this be a seperate database again?

Comment: If messages are not the main part of your app, you can set up a server-side script that copies the outgoing messages to the recipient as incoming message. If your app's primary purpose is a messaging system, though, you should consider an alternative setup.